# Converting Surface_mesh<Epick::Point_3> to Surface_mesh<Epeck::Point_3>

Tags: cgal

I have a `Surface_mesh\<Epick::Point_3\>` and need a `Surface_mesh\<Epeck::Point_3\>`.

It looks like I can convert between the *two via polygon soup*, but I am hoping there's a better alternative. :)

Is there any better option? please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [`copy_face_graph()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLHelperFct.html#ga2d3eb044bfe42eab566779ce32216c11)